# Horas estimadas usando un check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla en a cual tengo tres campos los cuales son:

```
create table horas
(
    fechaEntrada datetime,
    fechaSalida datetime,
    horasEstimadas int
);
```

y tengo que hacer una restriccion en la tabla que es, que las horas estimadas no deben ser mayor a las horas que hay en la fecha de entrada y de la fecha de salida.

Intente con un CHECK y adentro con un DATEDIFF pero siempre me marca error.

```
horasEstimadas int check (horasEstimadas <= (select DATEDIFF(DD, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)))
```

Y me manda este error:

Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Estoy usando SQL SERVER 2008.

No se que hacer, de antemano gracias por leer.

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/96467/edit) e incluye el código de tu restricción `CHECK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algunos problemas que veo con tu sentencia de creación: el primero te lo dice el error, es que no puedes usar una subconsulta como parte de un `CHECK` que es lo que está haciendo al usar un `SELECT`, por otro lado haces un [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) por `DD` que son días y los comparas con un campo que parecieran ser horas, y por último, el problema mayor es que no puedes implementar un `CHECK` a nivel columna usando datos de otras columnas, es decir puedes implementar algo como `horasEstimadas int check (horasEstimadas <= 24)` pero no usar otras columnas en la verificación. Para hacer eso debes implementar un `CONSTRAINT` a nivel de fila, que se dispara al completarse el `INSERT/UPDATE`, en definitiva tu sentencia quedaría así:

```
create table horas
(
    fechaEntrada datetime,
    fechaSalida datetime,
    horasEstimadas int,

    CONSTRAINT chk_horasEstimadas CHECK (horasEstimadas <= DATEDIFF(hh, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida))
);
```

Nota, que reemplace `DD` por `HH` en [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)